# Xamarin FirebaseStorage upload image

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-storage

I can't figure out how to upload an image to FirebaseStorge.

```
 var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.Instance.Reference.Child(FilePaths.FIREBASE_IMAGE_DIR + "/" + auth.CurrentUser.Uid + "/photo" + (count + 1));`
```

There are 3 options:

```
storageRef.PutStream(); storageRef.PutFile(); storageRef.PutBytes(); 

FilePath = "/storage/emulator/0/Pictures/...."
```

How can I convert this file to be able to upload it in firebase.
I'm new in Xamarin and I can't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this post, I used his explanation to do the same thing, and it works real good: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-image-uploading-to-firebase/

Answer (score 0):

StorageReference storageReference=null;

```
        if (fileBytes != null)
        {          
            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.Instance.GetReference("postImages/"+"123");
            storageReference.PutBytes(fileBytes)
                .AddOnSuccessListener(taskCompletionListeners)
                .AddOnFailureListener(taskCompletionListeners);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please explain your solution.